# Is exiting a stored procedure before using a commit harmful?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I tried searching for this but I have not found anything. If I have something like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE QQ
AS

BEGIN TRANSACTION

BEGIN TRY

    -- return early and skip commit here
    IF (Condition = true)
      RETURN 0

    COMMIT TRANSACTION

END TRY

BEGIN CATCH

    ROLLBACK

END CATCH
```

What will happen with the transaction?

Comment: Remember that TSQL effectively use a counter to determine if a transaction is open or not -- if this counter is not appropriately decremented ...

Comment: Yea, that is what I was thinking

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It will stay open until you `COMMIT`, `ROLLBACK`, or the connection is closed and that spid is killed.

This will block other processes and cause all kinds of other issues.

As a rule always run a check like below in your `CATCH` block to make sure you close up cleanly.

```
IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
ROLLBACK
```

or

```
WHILE @@Trancount > 0
BEGIN
   ROLLBACK
END
```

Comment: Although the forced rollbacks may not play nicely with other code/sprocs... best to make each unit self-cleaning IMOHO.

Comment: @pst - Sorry, I meant inside his `CATCH` block. I'll clarify.

Comment: Maybe add a flag variable @Return_Value and jump to a place in the code where it rollsback or commits depending on the flag and then returns the flag

Comment: @Gixonita - there are loads of examples of proven error trapping code in TSQL.  Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Thing is that I'm not trapping an error, for that I would just leave the Try-Catch block. I dont want to continue executing the rest of the SP if a condition is met somewhere in the middle (which would make the rest of the code invalid since this condition was met)

Comment: @Gixonita - then use `TRY...CATCH` and just execute a `RAISERROR` in the event your condition is not met.  It will escape to the `CATCH`.

Comment: @Gixonita - you probably want error trapping regardless, so you may as well use it if you have it.

Answer (score 1):

Just to be sure, I would perform a ROLLBACK before you exit the statement. Depending of your database software, they could perform an auto commit on exit.